# Can I see relationships in the list view in KeystoneJS?

Tags: node.js, content-management-system, keystonejs

In my KeystoneJS (v4) setup I have the following lists:

- Stores
- Product Categories
- Tags

The stores can have categories associated with them.

If I open up a category I can see it's **Relationships** (stores that use a certain category).

[image]

But, is it possible to see these relationships in the list layout as well? Not seeing it in the docs...

[image]

Comment: Please mark an answer if it resolved your question.

Comment: The answer below does not answer the question as it is - but the comment/discussion below it does. Basically the answer is: This is not possible in Keystone V4. You could update your answer to say "Adding the relationship to the columns is not possible".

Answer (score 0):

Adding the relationship to the column is not possible.

Comment: I am referring to the columns, yes. But in your example you can only show fields that are on "YourModel". I was thinking the other way around (see the bottom half of my first picture). 

A simple example. "Articles" and "Authors". Each article has an author. In the list of articles I can show the related author - like you show in your code. However in the list of authors I would like to see the articles they have written... and I don't know if that is possible? I do know though that if I open up each individual author I could see the list of articles they have written.

Comment: Right, I understand now. However, I don't think that is possible with keystone as it is now. Sorry I couldn't be more helpful.

Comment: You were very helpful :) I don't think is possible as well. Just wanted to get someone else to confirm it as well.